# NextAuth Programmatically SignOut on server-side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

How would I programmatically sign out a user in Next-Auth on the server side?

Inside /api/auth/[...nextauth].js there is a jwt function:

```
const callbacks = {    
 async jwt ({ token, user }) {
   
  // How to sign out a user?
  signOut();  <--- can't use this on the server side
 
  }
 }
```

Unfortunately, the signOut() function is only for the client side. It produces an error if used here.

I have read the very bare-bones Next Auth REST API page and I can't get a POST call to "/api/auth/signout" to work. If that is the correct method can someone show me some working code? Does it need any kind of authorization token?

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api

Thanks!